# PHP timer without script pause/delay

Tags: php, timer, delay

So I just want to write this quick and dirty module to a program that takes the current time, echos a string, and then waits x minutes and echos another string. The only thing is, is this little module stops the rest of the program until it's finished. Any way around this?

Comment: What would happen if your program stopped/crashed/etc before x minutes? There are some ways of doing it by starting other PHP threads and sharing PIDs, etc. But are you sure you want to go that route?

Comment: It's not so much of it stopping or crashing as much as it's pausing. Every method I have tried to do this works but it pauses the rest of the program until the alloted time is up, so it can't function.

Comment: Right, and it does that for a good reason. PHP doesn't natively support events or multithreading, I just think there may be a better solution for what you're trying to do.

Comment: What would you suggest before I give _fork a go?

Comment: Would a cronjob have a similar end-result? Forking is expensive and sometimes considered bad practice when dealing with PHP, especially if your application is a web-app and someone could theoretically spam running processes, which would be a bad thing. It's all very situational, it's just important to be aware of the side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate the current process on which it is running to leave 1 process waiting and the other one do what it has to do.

To fork a PHP process you have to use [pcntl_fork](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php)

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse forking would do the trick, but why not use the [ticks functionality](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php) in PHP?

Consider this example:

```
declare(ticks=1);

function tick() {
   // check if the interval is correct before proceding
   $mem = memory_get_usage(true);
   echo "Using $mem bytes right now";
}

register_tick_function('tick');

// do all kinds of things in your main program here
while(true) {
   usleep(50000);
}
```

While sleeping it will periodically call the tick function, without having to invoke it manually. The only caveat is that if a particular operation takes a very long time to complete (e.g. a database query) the ticks will not fire until this operation is complete.